# Redux-saga - TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have following `saga`, but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` error.

`saga.js`

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import LoginActions from '../Redux/LoginRedux'
import AuthAPI from '../Services/Auth'

// attempts to login
export function * login ({ email, password, save }) {
    try {
        const user = yield call(AuthAPI.login, {user: {email, password }})
        // dispatch successful logins
        yield put(LoginActions.loginSuccess(user.data))
    } catch(e) {
        yield put(LoginActions.loginFailure(e))
    }
}
```

`Services/Auth.js`

```
import request from 'superagent'

export default class AuthAPI {
    static login (data) {
        return request.post('/sessions.json').send(data)
    }
}
```

Any helps are appreciated

Comment: I think it can't find redux-saga/effects. Try to do import reduxSaga from 'redux-saga/effects' And then console.log(reduxSaga). Do you get undefined here?